# How to reference JavaScript file one level up in IIS Express?

Tags: javascript

There's a lot of posts about this theme, but the following doesn't work for me:

```
<script id="dxis_script1" type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/scripts-LostEnergyCalculation.js"></script>
```

So, how to reference JavaScript file that is located one level up of web root folder in Script folder?

Comment: Script folder should be hosted on IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write "one level up of web root folder". You are trying to link to this from the client browser. This is not possible. If you want to host the script file publicly, it must be within the served root folder.

Comment: I cite the passage where he specified the information in my answer.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I just re-read that part of the question and removed both comment and downvote. And also upvoted.

Comment: Cheers! . . . .